# Specificity clash: Utility class being overwritten by attribute selector

Tags: css, attributes, css-specificity

In my app, submit buttons and links look identical.

The way I have structured my css is like this:

```
.button, input[type=submit]{
    //default colour
    background:grey;
}

.button-primary{
    background:green;
}

.button-danger{
    background:red;
}
```

If I wanted a red background on a submit button, I was hoping I would be able to simply add the `.button-danger` class to it. But unfortunately this does nothing and the submit remains grey, because `input[type=submit]` is more specific than `.button-danger`.

What is an elegant way to get around this?

Comment: ...looks fine? http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/yTFSJ/ also note you cant use `//` in CSS, use `/*...*/`

Comment: @SW4, it only seems to work, since the `//default color` is a syntax error that prevents the rule from taking any effect.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - good call...In my haste and lack of caffeine...I overlooked the fact I had commented on it but not removed..

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to:

```
.button, input[type=submit]:not([class^=button-]){
    background:grey;
}
```

What this does is add the `:not` selector to only style `input` buttons with the default style, if they dont have subsequent button classes added to them, classes which start with `button-`

[More on `:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.
>
> The specificity of the :not pseudo-class is the specificity of its
>   argument. The :not pseudo-class does not add to the selector
>   specificity, unlike other pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 1):

Add something to the selector to make it more specific. For example:

```
.button-danger, input[type=submit].button-danger {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP has multiple button classes, so would need to extend the CSS for each of them

Answer (score -1):

Use of "!important keyword" is always possible. something like this:

```
.button-danger{
    background:red !important;
}
```